# Avoid direct translation of "public static final" with ProGuard

Tags: java, android, proguard, obfuscation

How can i tell to ProGuard not to do this?

```
In Class A
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Utility.NO_SESSION, 0).show();
-> with ProGuard  <--
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please login", 0).show();

In Class Utility
  public static final String NO_SESSION = "Please login";
-> with ProGuard  <--
  this string does not even exist
```

This just makes things easier to read

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This behavior is the point of proguard, if you do not like it, why are you using proguard?

Comment: If you want your compiled code easy to read after being decompiled, simply disable Proguard. The purpose of Proguard is to minimize, optimize and obfuscate your compiled application.

Comment: I think they are saying proguard is making it easier to read by in-lining constants.

Comment: That's not even a ProGuard thing in particular; the JLS specifies that compile-time constants WILL be inlined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really makes no difference to someone trying to read reverse engineered code whether they have to look up a constant or it's inline.

But if you like you can add:

```
-keep class your.package.Utility { public static *; }
```

To your `proguard-project.txt`